# Knot to attach gear to a beam

Tags: knots, paracord

My outdoor gear has been relegated to the garage but I want to keep it off the ground, I have a beam and paracord and am using a double fisherman's bend and a midshipman knot to keep it elevated but it's really difficult to raise it and lower it as the weight tightens the knot.

What's a good knot that I can use to hang my gear, ideally I want to be able to raise and lower it from the ground?

Comment: What shape is the beam (e.g., I, square, round) and do you have access to one end?

Comment: @StrongBad it's square and I don't have access to the end of the beam

Comment: What's the weight, what's the height of the bar and how heigh should the great hang?

Comment: It's up to 15 kilos, the bar is 9ft high and I'd like to get it as close to the bar as I can

Comment: Pulling 15 kilos with paracord? the skin on my hands hurts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of multiple options for solving this problem.

1. [Tensionless Hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/tensionless/index.php?Categ=typehitches&LogoImage=LogoGrog.jpg&Website=www.animatedknots.com#ScrollPoint) i.e. wrap the rope around the beam enough times that it doesn't slip and unwrap to lower.
2. Loop a sling over the beam, connect the ends with a carabiner and then counterbalance the items.
3. Tie one strand of parachute cord to the beam, and then attach the items to that strand with short lengths secured to the main strand with [friction hitches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_friction_hitch_knots).

Answer (score 5):

I come form a coal mining town, in the mines they call the change rooms the 'dry', because mines can be very wet places and the 'dry' is where you'd dry out your clothes. Before they started putting ventilated lockers in the drys, they used to hang their clothes on hooks under baskets that they'd raise up to the ceiling with a rope and pulley system
to where is was warm and all your things could dry:

[image]

[image]<sup>[Source](http://rebrn.com/re/washing-room-of-abandoned-zeche-hugo-coal-mine-clothing-and-valu-339268/)</sup>

[image]<sup>[Source](http://booksbyreneschmidt.blogspot.ca/2010/06/touring-underground-at-t-1-mine.html)</sup>

This is what I'd recommend for you. A cheap simple set up would be to use a couple of closed eye bolts in the ceiling in place of pulleys, one on the beam, and another in the ceiling over by the wall, then pound a nail into the wall down at a height that's easy to reach.

Thread your paracord through the eye-bolts, tie a hook, carabiner or even a basket to the end you're going to raise up, then tie the other end of your cord to the nail with your item at the height you want it while lowered. Pull your gear all the way up to the roof, and tie a loop on a bight or butterfly knot in the cord that you can hook onto the nail to keep everything up. When you want your stuff down, all you need to do is unhook the loop from the nail and lower it down. No more tying knots every time you want something up or down.